# No se genera la clave foránea en tabla de SQFLITE en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo dos tablas generadas con el siguiente SQL

```
  static const String createTableFarmersSQL =
      "CREATE TABLE Farmers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "createdAt TEXT,"
      "updatedAt TEXT,"
      "name TEXT,"
      "city TEXT,"
      "email TEXT,"
      "phoneNumber INTEGER,"
      "description TEXT);";

  static const String createTableFormsSQL=
      "CREATE TABLE Forms (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "idFarmer INTEGER, "
      "createdAt TEXT,"
      "updatedAt TEXT,"
      "name TEXT,"
      "type TEXT,"
      "crop TEXT,"
      "finished NUMERIC,"
      "FOREIGN KEY(idFarmer) REFERENCES Farmers (id));";
```

Y se lanzan mediante la siguiente función:

```
  Future<Database> _openDB() async
  {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(),"SILAGEAPPDB6.db"),
        onCreate: (db,version)
        async {
          await db.execute(Constants.createTableFarmersSQL);
          await db.execute(Constants.createTableFormsSQL);
        }, version: 2

    );

  }
```

Las tablas se crean y no aparece error, sin embargo, el campo "idFarmers" de la tabla "Forms" no es reconocido como clave foránea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí podéis ver como no aparece el icono que representa que el campo es clave foránea.
Aparentemente la sintaxis del SQL la tengo bien, así que no sé donde está el fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que tengas que habilitar la opción que permite utilizar `foreign keys` en `sqlite`. La función `openDataBase` tiene un parámetro `onConfigure`, en este parámetro tu vas a tener que pasarle un comando para poder habilitar la restricción de `foreign key`:

```
Future<Database> _openDB() async
  {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(),"SILAGEAPPDB6.db"),
        onConfigure: (db) async {
          await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
        },
        onCreate: (db,version)
        async {
          await db.execute(Constants.createTableFarmersSQL);
          await db.execute(Constants.createTableFormsSQL);
        }, version: 2
    );
  }
```

Una vez hecho este cambio es posible que tengas que cambiar la versión de la bd, o simplemente dejarla en versión 1 y desinstalar e instalar nuevamente la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo que "PRAGMA" es el nombre de la tabla donde se deben habilitar las claves foráneas?

Comment: No, pragma es el comando para poder utilizar las claves foraneas

Comment: Parece que ya me funciona, aunque en el inspector de la base de datos no aparece el icono de clave foranea en el campo. Pero he hecho la prueba insertando un registro con un valor de clave foranea que no existe y da error, luego el campo se debe estar reconociendo como tal.